# Reading all response headers using libCurl in C

Tags: c, libcurl

How do I read response headers from a response using libCurl in C?

The MAN page says this:

```
size_t function( void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
```

What is the **stream** here? Do I read headers from stream or from ptr?

I am currently trying to read code from ptr and passing a struct for stream.

And the only response header is see is http/1. 0 ok.  Nothing else and I am pretty sure the response has more headers

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sepheaders.html) example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter isn't a stream, it's a void* to your userdata if used.  The data to read is in *ptr, and this function will be called once for each header received.

(The last parameter is often used to point back to an C++ object instance through a static method using the C-style API...)

One example here:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.curl.library/28803

Comment: Thank you. this helped a lot. I was not returning the # bytes read. I was not returning anything.

Comment: @Joe The link is dead.

Comment: It wasn’t 8 years ago